# SQL query rather than CakePHP style query

Tags: sql, cakephp-2.0

I have a really complex query: so much table (and... so much nested model). I feel more comfortable, using raw SQL query rather than CakePHP query syntax. 
As far as I know, I should prefear CakePHP syntax, cause it is almost immune to attack.

Considering that I won't use Cake's syntax, there's a way to join the security of cake approach with the practicalness of raw SQL approach?

Comment: You can try use PDO with [Prepare statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) without bothering what user enters letter, number or illegal character. Still I would prefer stick with cake as much it possible due models management reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use pdo adapter for mysql, its provide security for sql injection.

I addition you can use [Sanitize::clean](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html) and [Sanitize::escape](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html) to escape your query.

Comment: I had even thinked to validate input arguments and if needed raise error to avoid real query. For example: if the where needs a int, then, if i get a string raise error.

Comment: if you do it, you can be sure that you protect your query from sql injection.